# How to recover indices from a view of an numpy array produced by slicing?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am currently trying to subclass `np.ndarray` to have another array of the same dimension as one of its attributes. If I take a slice of my subclass, I need to have the attribute array of this newly created instance (which is a view of the original array) to be sliced to the same indices.

This would be possible if in

```
a = np.array(range(10))
b = a[:5]
```

I could somehow recover the key `slice(None, 5)` from the object `b`. Is that possible and if yes, how so?

So far I only know that I can see that `b` is a view of `a` by accessing its `base` attribute, which unfortunately is not enough for my use case.

Comment: You mean solely based on object `b`right?

Comment: Preferably, yes. But of course I have access to `a` via `b.base`.

Comment: the view does not record ow it was created

Comment: @hpaulj Just curious do you know how to get the offset of a view?

Comment: I can deduce it from the `arr.__array_interface__` data.